# How to mock a call for inner method for Junit

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I have the following:

```
public class A{

  private SOAPMessage msg;
  SOAPMessage getmSOAP()
    {
        return msg;
    }

    public Map<String,String> getAllProfiles(String type) throws SOAPException
    {

        NodeList profilesTypes = getmsoapResponse().getSOAPBody().getElementsByTagName("profileType");

        ...
    }
}
```

I want to mock the call of `getmsoapResponse()` in side of `getAllProfiles(String value)` and to inject my own `SOAPMessage`.

Was trying few things which did not work:
Run A:

```
m_mock = Mockito.mock(A.class);
Mockito.when(m_mock .getmsoapResponse()).thenReturn(m_SOAPRespones);
Mockito.when(m_mock .getAllProfiles("")).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Run B:

```
m_mock = spy(new A())
doReturn(m_SOAPRespones).when(m_mock ).getmsoapResponse();
```

Both did not work, what did i do wrong?

---

Run B did work at the end , had a small bug.

As well the suggested answer is working well.

Comment: Your second approach looks right. What exactly do you mean when you say it "did not work"?

Comment: you where right :) had a bug :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss only one thing: you also need to mock the result of `.getSoapBody()` here.

Assumptions are made about classes below; just replace with the appropriate classes; note also that I respect the Java naming conventions, which you should too:

```
final A mock = spy(new A());

final SOAPResponse response = mock(SOAPResponse.class);
final SOAPBody body = mock(SOAPBody.class);

// Order does not really matter, of course, but bottom up makes it clearer
// SOAPBody
when(body.whatever()).thenReturn(whatIsNeeded);

// SOAPResponse
when(response.getSoapBody()).thenReturn(body);

// Your A class
when(mock.getSoapResponse()).thenReturn(response);
when(mock.getAllProfiles("")).thenCallRealMethod();
```

In short: you need to mock all elements in the chain. And please do follow Java naming conventions, it makes it easier for people who read your code later on ;)